# How can I package my Django project with a server software so that it is ready to run on any machine?

Tags: django, apache, server, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I want to share the project to multiple clients so that they can use it on their own local networks without doing a lot of work. So somehow packaging the Django project along with a secure server software together so that it easily can be run on any machine would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Docker might be your best bet, you will need to create a docker image and on any machine that you'll want to run, have the docker client run this image. running it after installing the docker client can be a 1 line in the command line.

an example:
https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/